# Average if cell and and adjacent cell are not NA (Excel)

Tags: excel, average

I am trying to calculate an average value if the rows in two columns are not NA. This is to aid me in calculating an average weight of fish. Here are some example data:

```
Country,fish weight,fish number
Belgium,264.5,NA
Channel Islands,NA,NA
England,625,281000
Netherlands,737,690000
France,189.5,NA
```

In this example, the average function would create an average of England and Netherlands weights but not include Belgium and France's weights as the number of fish is not known.

I tried doing this 'averageifs' statement but I can only get it to includes all data.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(weights,weights,"<>0", numbers,"<>0")
```

Comment: probably NA is not 0, and therefore it is included. Also it is unclear if you defined your named ranges properly. Seeing that you only want to do an average when the number of fish is included you probably want a weighted average. Look into using sumproduct devided by sum for that.

Comment: **Awesome, thank you. I just changed the "<>0" to "<>NA" and it worked. Much love**

Answer (score 0):

NA is not the same as 0, therefore your formula will see those cells as different from 0 and take them into account. Change your criteria into `"<>NA"`